# PHP quiz script answer highlight

Tags: php

I have a PHP script and MSSQL tables, I got the answer key in a variable stored in `$right_answer` and user selected answers in `$user_answer_select` THe format is something like this

```
5+10?

A) 10
B) 15
C) 20
D) 25
E) 50

Answer key: B
```

what I want to do is put a check mark next to B if its correct and a X if it is wrong, how would I make the if else statements here?

This is the code I currently have

```
if(($user_answer_select == $right_answer) && $user_answer_select == 'a') $a_sel = "<img src=\"tick_icon.gif\">";
else if(($user_answer_select == $right_answer) && $user_answer_select == 'b') $b_sel = "<img src=\"tick_icon.gif\">";
else if(($user_answer_select == $right_answer) && $user_answer_select == 'c') $c_sel = "<img src=\"tick_icon.gif\">";
else if(($user_answer_select == $right_answer) && $user_answer_select == 'd') $d_sel = "<img src=\"tick_icon.gif\">";
else if(($user_answer_select == $right_answer) && $user_answer_select == 'e') $e_sel = "<img src=\"tick_icon.gif\">";
```

This is wrong because some of the questions that don't have answers for are highlighted as true. What's the way to do this?

Comment: Am I right that you don't have a specific question and just want use to write the code that solves your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$answers = array ( "A"=>10, "B"=>15, "C"=>20, "D"=>25, "E"=>50 );
$right_answer = "B";
$user_selected_answer = "A";

echo "5+10?<br/>";

foreach ($answers as $key => $value) {
  echo $key.") ".$value;
  if ($value === $user_selected_answer) {
    if ($value === $right_answer){ echo "check!"; }
    else { echo "X"; }
  }
  echo "<br/>";
}

echo "Answer key: $right_answer";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $user_answer_select == $right_answer ) {
    $correct = true;
} else {
    $correct = false;
}
```

Then in the correct answer on the form:

```
<?php echo $correct == true ? 'x' : ''; ?>
```